# Unmarshal nested JSON structure

Tags: json, go

http://play.golang.org/p/f6ilWnWTjm

I am trying to decode the following string but only getting null values.

How do I decode nested JSON structure in Go?

I want to convert the following to map data structure.

```
package main

import (
  "encoding/json"
  "fmt"
)

func main() {
  jStr := `
{
    "AAA": {
        "assdfdff": ["asdf"],
        "fdsfa": ["1231", "123"]
    }
}
`
  type Container struct {
    Key string `json:"AAA"`
  }
  var cont Container

  json.Unmarshal([]byte(jStr), &cont)
  fmt.Println(cont)
}
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use nested structs in Go to match the nested structure in JSON.

Here's one example of how to handle your example JSON:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "log"
)

func main() {
    jStr := `
    {
        "AAA": {
            "assdfdff": ["asdf"],
            "fdsfa": ["1231", "123"]
        }
    }
    `

    type Inner struct {
        Key2 []string `json:"assdfdff"`
        Key3 []string `json:"fdsfa"`
    }
    type Container struct {
        Key Inner `json:"AAA"`
    }
    var cont Container
    if err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jStr), &cont); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", cont)
}
```

[playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/bOWRZS6ntu)

You can also use an anonymous type for the inner struct:

```
type Container struct {
    Key struct {
        Key2 []string `json:"assdfdff"`
        Key3 []string `json:"fdsfa"`
    }  `json:"AAA"`
}
```

[playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/if3q2yfqzb)

or both the outer and inner structs:

```
var cont struct {
    Key struct {
        Key2 []string `json:"assdfdff"`
        Key3 []string `json:"fdsfa"`
    } `json:"AAA"`
}
```

[playground link](http://play.golang.org/p/aH2YbnXaWE)

If you don't know the field names in the inner structure, then use a map:

```
type Container struct {
    Key map[string][]string `json:"AAA"`
}
```

http://play.golang.org/p/gwugHlCPLK

There are more options. Hopefully this gets you on the right track.

Comment: i was comming across an issue where my nested stuct was returned empty like so "{{  }}" the issue was a space in setting the json name in the struct . this didnt work as there was a space`json: "name"`. but this did `json:"name"`. face palm!

Answer (score 7):

First of all: Don't ignore errors returned by a function or method unless you have a very good reason to do so.

If you make the following change to the code:

```
err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(jStr), &cont)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}
```

You will see the error message telling you why the value is empty:

> json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type string

Simply put: `Key` cannot be of type `string`, so you have to use a different type. You have several option on how to decode it depending on the characteristics of the `Key` value:

- If the structure is static, use another struct to match this structure.
- If the structure is dynamic, use `interface{}` (or `map[string]interface{}` if it is always of type JSON object)
- If the value is not to be accessed, only to be used in later JSON encoding, or if the decoding is to be delayed, use `json.RawMessage`