# Why does Go error when trying to marshal this JSON?

Tags: json, go, struct

I'm trying a rather simple example of trying to decode a JSON file into some structs using golang. However, when attempting to I get the error that

> json: cannot unmarshal object into Go value of type []main.Track

Which I don't understand. Here's the code in question, and the JSON can be [found here](http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettoptracks&api_key=c1572082105bd40d247836b5c1819623&format=json&country=Netherlands).

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

// Tracks a group of Track types
type Tracks struct {
    Tracks []Track
}

// Track represents a singular track
type Track struct {
    Name   string
    URL    string
    Artist Artist
}

// Artist represents a single artist
type Artist struct {
    Name string
    MBID string
    URL  string
}

func main() {
    url := "http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.gettoptracks&api_key=c1572082105bd40d247836b5c1819623&format=json&country=Netherlands"
    response, err := http.Get(url)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", err)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    defer response.Body.Close()

    var tracks Tracks
    decodeErr := json.NewDecoder(response.Body).Decode(&tracks)

    if decodeErr != nil {
        fmt.Printf("%s\n", decodeErr)
        os.Exit(1)
    }

    for _, track := range tracks.Tracks {
        fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", track.Artist.Name, track.Name)
    }
}
```

My initial thought was maybe you need to categorize every single JSON value with structs, which I didn't do, but upon reading [this article](https://eager.io/blog/go-and-json/) which says:

> There are two answers to this. The easy option, for when you know what your data will look like, is to parse the JSON into a struct you’ve defined. **Any field which doesn’t fit in the struct will just be ignored.** We’ll cover that option first.

Which leads me to believe that it isn't that.

What am I doing wrong in this scenario?

Comment: If you want to avoid this kind of issues you can try using the [json-to-go tool](https://mholt.github.io/json-to-go/). It basically converts json to a type definition.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the JSON structure of the response to your query you'll see that a single object with a `tracks` property is returned.

```
{
    "tracks": {
        "track": [ {...} ]
    }
}
```

If you compare this to to the given structs you can see that the structure does not align. Your given `Tracks` struct has a field that is a slice of `Track`s. If I were to cast this as JSON it would be represented as the following.

```
{ 
    "tracks": [ { ... } ]
}
```

This is the root of your error. The JSON decoder is expecting the `tracks` field of the root JSON object to be an array. What is returned is an object that contains the `tracks` property but its values is another JSON object which contains the `track` property which **is** the array of tracks. You could update your structures to reflect this schema as follows.

```
// A response object from the API
type Response struct {
    Tracks Tracks
}

// Tracks a group of Track types
type Tracks struct {
    Track []Track
}

// Track represents a singular track
type Track struct {
    Name   string
    URL    string
    Artist Artist
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The structure of the Go types must match the structure in the JSON data. The application is missing a level of nesting for the bolded range of this JSON:   {"tracks":{**"track":**[{

Here's how to update the types to match the JSON:

```
type Tracks struct {
    Tracks struct {
      Track []Track
    }
}

...

for _, track := range tracks.Tracks.Track {
    fmt.Printf("%s: %s\n", track.Artist.Name, track.Name)
}
```

Comment: Could you explain this a little more? I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: I think I see, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25966781/998117) details it a bit, but isn't it optional to do it this way (ie: me using two outer structs to do it should still work)?