# golang json iterate not supporting indexing

Tags: json, go

I've got a problem with my json parsing in golang.
I used some code to parse the json into a `map[string]interface{}{}` but when I try to iterate through  a nested field, the error `(type interface {} does not support indexing)` is triggered.

I'd like to get the following informations :

- iterate through each `response->blogs` and then get the url of original_size photo that lays in `response->posts->blog_n->photos->original_size`
- `meta->status`
- `response->blog->total_posts` and `response->blog->name`

Here's a link to a [playground](https://play.golang.org/p/vcRu2cAhSk)
Thank you for your help !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is there a reason you want to use a `map`? To do the indexing you're talking about, with maps, I think you would need *nested maps* as well.

Have you considered using **nested structs**, as described here, [Go Unmarshal nested JSON structure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25966567/go-unmarshal-nested-json-structure) and [Unmarshaling nested JSON objects in Golang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21268000/unmarshaling-nested-json-objects-in-golang) ?

For your JSON data, here is a sample -- working but limited -- `struct`. Go will ignore the fields you don't use.

```
func main() {
    //Creating the maps for JSON
    data := &Header{}

    //Parsing/Unmarshalling JSON encoding/json
    err := json.Unmarshal([]byte(input), &data)

    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", m)
}
type Header struct {
    Response struct { 
        Blog struct {
            Title string `json:"title"`
        } `json:"blog"`
        Posts []struct {
            Id int64 `json:"id"`
        } `json:"posts"`
    } `json:"response"`
}
```

To get JSON with Go to do what you want, you have to brush up on JSON and it's relation to Go *types*.

**Notice posts**:
`slice`s of `struct`s are, in JSON, `array`s of `object`s, `[{..},{..}]`

In Go, **only exported** fields will be filled.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! nope, no reason I just found this piece of code. Would you be able to provide me the complete struct please ?

Comment: @gmolveau the complete struct would be pretty large, because the json is pretty big. I'm not really sure what you need, but I thing you could modify the code I provided to get you there :) cheers

Comment: Thank you for your answer :D

Comment: @gmolveau sure! I'm glad it helps, and if it's the solution, then could you mark it as correct? (the green check mark) :)

Comment: I'm indeed going to go with your solution ! :)

Answer (score 1):

this error appear because your map[key-type]val-type, and you to try get value as nested map.

you can use [Type Assertion](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to get value.

```
result := m["response"].(map[string]interface{}) 
fmt.Printf("%+v\n", result["blog"])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer !