# How to flatten out a nested json structure in go

Tags: go, bson

I am getting nested data from mongo and I want to flatten that out in a structure to store it in a csv file.

The data looks like this:

```
{
    "_id" : "bec7bfaa-7a47-4f61-a463-5966a2b5c8ce",
    "data" : {
        "driver" : {
            "etaToStore" : 156
        },
        "createdAt" : 1532590052,
        "_id" : "07703a33-a3c3-4ad5-9e06-d05063474d8c"
    }
}
```

And the structure I want to eventually get should be something like this

```
type EventStruct struct {
    Id                  string      `bson:"_id"`
    DataId              string      `bson:"data._id"`
    EtaToStore          string      `bson:"data.driver.etaToStore"`
    CreatedAt           int         `bson:"data.createdAt"`
}
```

This doesn't work, so following [some SO answers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25966781/830230) I broke it down into multiple structures:

```
// Creating a structure for the inner struct that I will receive from the query
type DriverStruct struct {
    EtaToStore  int     `bson:"etaToStore"`
}

type DataStruct struct {
    Id          string `bson:"_id"`
    Driver      DriverStruct `bson:"driver"`
    CreatedAt   int `bson:"createdAt"`
}
// Flattenning out the structure & getting the fields we need only
type EventStruct struct {
    Id                  string      `bson:"_id"`
    Data                DataStruct  `bson:"data"`
}
```

This gets all the data from the Mongo query result but it's nested:

```
{
  "Id": "bec7bfaa-7a47-4f61-a463-5966a2b5c8ce",
  "Data": {
     "Id": a33-a3c3-4ad5-9e06-d05063474d8c,
     "Driver": {
        "EtaToStore": 156
     },
     "CreatedAt": 1532590052
  }
}
```

What I want to end up with is:

```
{
  "Id": "bec7bfaa-7a47-4f61-a463-5966a2b5c8ce",
  "DataId": "a33-a3c3-4ad5-9e06-d05063474d8c",
  "EtaToStore": 156,
  "CreatedAt": 1532590052
}
```

I'm sure there's an easy way to do this but I can't figure it out, help!

Comment: why the negative vote :/?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can implement the `json.Unmarshaler` interface to add a custom method to unmarshal the json. Then in that method, you can use the nested struct format, but return the flattened one at the end.

```
func (es *EventStruct) UnmarshalJSON(data []byte) error {
    // define private models for the data format

    type driverInner struct {
        EtaToStore int `bson:"etaToStore"`
    }

    type dataInner struct {
        ID        string      `bson:"_id" json:"_id"`
        Driver    driverInner `bson:"driver"`
        CreatedAt int         `bson:"createdAt"`
    }

    type nestedEvent struct {
        ID   string    `bson:"_id"`
        Data dataInner `bson:"data"`
    }

    var ne nestedEvent

    if err := json.Unmarshal(data, &ne); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    // create the struct in desired format
    tmp := &EventStruct{
        ID:         ne.ID,
        DataID:     ne.Data.ID,
        EtaToStore: ne.Data.Driver.EtaToStore,
        CreatedAt:  ne.Data.CreatedAt,
    }

    // reassign the method receiver pointer
    // to store the values in the struct
    *es = *tmp
    return nil
}
```

Runnable example: https://play.golang.org/p/83VHShfE5rI

Comment: Thanks Zak, that's a pretty clean solution

Comment: Running the code example at the link returns: {ID: DataID:07703a33-a3c3-4ad5-9e06-d05063474d8c EtaToStore:156 CreatedAt:1532590052}. The value for ID at the top level does not show the expected value "bec7bfaa-7a47-4f61-a463-5966a2b5c8ce"

Comment: fixed by adding json:"_id" to struct type `nestedEvent` @Amitabh

Answer (score 6):

This question is a year and a half old, but I ran into it today while reacting to an API update which put me in the same situation, so here's my solution (which, admittedly, I haven't tested with `bson`, but I'm assuming the `json` and `bson` field tag reader implementations handle them the same way)

**Embedded (sometimes referred to as anonymous) fields can capture JSON, so you can compose several structs into a compound one which behaves like a single structure.**

```
{
    "_id" : "bec7bfaa-7a47-4f61-a463-5966a2b5c8ce",
    "data" : {
        "driver" : {
            "etaToStore" : 156
        },
        "createdAt" : 1532590052,
        "_id" : "07703a33-a3c3-4ad5-9e06-d05063474d8c"
    }
}
```

```
type DriverStruct struct {
    EtaToStore          string      `bson:"etaToStore"`

type DataStruct struct {
    DriverStruct                    `bson:"driver"`
    DataId              string      `bson:"_id"`
    CreatedAt           int         `bson:"createdAt"`
}

type EventStruct struct {
    DataStruct                      `bson:"data"`
    Id                  string      `bson:"_id"`
}
```

You can access the nested fields of an embedded struct as though the parent struct contained an equivalent field, so e.g. `EventStructInstance.EtaToStore` is a valid way to get at them.

Benefits:

- You don't have to implement the `Marshaller` or `Unmarshaller` interfaces, which is a little overkill for this problem
- Doesn't require any copying fields between intermediate structs
- Handles both marshalling and unmarshalling for free

[Read more about embedded fields here.](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding)

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Remove the tags on the embedded structs, otherwise they will be nested

Answer (score 3):

You can use basically the same logic as:

```
package utils

// FlattenIntegers flattens nested slices of integers
func FlattenIntegers(slice []interface{}) []int {
    var flat []int

    for _, element := range slice {
        switch element.(type) {
        case []interface{}:
            flat = append(flat, FlattenIntegers(element.([]interface{}))...)
        case []int:
            flat = append(flat, element.([]int)...)
        case int:
            flat = append(flat, element.(int))
        }
    }

    return flat
}
```

(Source: https://gist.github.com/Ullaakut/cb1305ede48f2391090d57cde355074f)

By adapting it for what's in your JSON. If you want it to be generic, then you'll need to support all of the types it can contain.